# Enabling Intellisense for Mocha

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, visual-studio-code

I'm running VS Code 1.0. I've already successfully added intellisense for a number of frameworks, i.e., Express, Restify, and even Gulp.

Now I'm trying to enable it for Mocha.

The minimum setup I'm doing is:

- Create a folder.
- `npm init`
- `npm install mocha`
- `typings install mocha --ambient`
- Open Code in said folder.
- Create a new file and try to type "describe".

Also, [this guy](https://github.com/vintem/TypescriptMochaWebpackDemo) got it working.

[image: Why does Code hate me??]

Answer (score 0):

You just have to ad jsconfig.json file to the root of your project. It can even be empty.

[Check this docs.](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript)